# Laravel correct URL is returning incorrect content

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-10

in Laravel, I have made a project to handle supervisors to supervisor their students PG or final year project,
here is a simple explanation of what the project is about,
every use can have many roles, you have student, supervisor, and admin. a supervisor can also be admin and likewise. but if it's a student, they can only be student.

the supervisor is able to comment or write a statement, grade and download the uploaded file in a chapter. the supervisor can also switch between each of their student/project.

every project has a project query and has many chapters, and chapter can have many tasks.
the project has a supervisor_id and student_id column.

the problem is for example this url /Project/1/Chapter/4
the content should be of project 1 and content of chapter 4 should be open, but it's the opposite, project 4 opens with chapter 1
but I see no signs that they variables have been switched at all.

I tried dd($chapter) and these and it's printing the wrong variables, in fact the universities own technician also took a look at this problem and tried many things, we still couldn't figure out what the problem was.

now for the url /Project/1/Chapter/1/Task/2 it works perfectly fine, but for this url /Project/1/Chapter/4  I'm facing this issue. I will include this one in the code too.

controller:

```
        public function Chapter( $project_id,$chapter_id)
    {
        $projects = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $chapters = Chapter::findOrFail($chapter_id);
    
        $supervisor = User::findOrFail(8);
        $SubProjects = Project::where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id)
            ->orderBy('student_id', 'asc')
            ->get();
    
        $studentIds = $SubProjects->pluck('student_id');
        $SubStudents = User::whereIn('id', $studentIds)
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->get();
    
        $current_student_id = $projects->student_id;
        $current_student = User::findOrFail($current_student_id);
    
        //dd($current_student);
    
        $project_query = $projects->project_query;
    
        return view('supervisor.chapter', compact('projects', 'SubStudents', 'SubProjects', 'chapters', 'project_query', 'current_student'));
    }

public function ChapterTask($project_id, $chapter_id, $task_id)
{
    $projects = Project::with('chapters.tasks')->find($project_id);
    $chapters = Chapter::findOrFail($chapter_id);
    $ActiveTask = $chapters->tasks()->findOrFail($task_id);

    $supervisor = User::findOrFail(8);
    $SubProjects = Project::where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id)
        ->orderBy('student_id', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $studentIds = $SubProjects->pluck('student_id');
    $SubStudents = User::whereIn('id', $studentIds)
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $current_student_id = $projects->student_id;
    $current_student = User::findOrFail($current_student_id);

    $project_query = $projects->first()->project_query;

    return view('supervisor.task', compact('projects', 'chapters', 'ActiveTask', 'project_query', 'current_student', 'SubProjects', 'SubStudents'));
}
```

route:

```
    Route::get('/Project/{project_id}/Chapter/{chapter_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Controller::class, 'Chapter']);
Route::get('/Project/{project_id}/Chapter/{Chapter_id}/Task/{Task_id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Controller::class, 'ChapterTask'])->name('ChapterTask');
```

layout app view:

```
            <li class="nav-item dropdown student-profile">
                <a href="{{ url('/ViewProjectorsupervisorProject/' . $projects->id) }}"
                    class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle"
                    id="dropdownUser2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32" height="32"
                        class="rounded-circle me-2">
                    <strong>{{ $current_student->full_name }}</strong>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-start">
                    @foreach ($SubProjects as $SubProject)
                        @foreach ($SubStudents as $SubStudent)
                            @if ($SubStudent->id === $SubProject->student_id)
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('/ViewProjectorsupervisorProject/' . $SubProject->id) }}"
                                        class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none">
                                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32"
                                            height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2">
                                        <p><strong>{{ $SubStudent->full_name }}</strong></p>
                                        <p>{{ $SubProject->title }}</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>



<!-- Sidebar-->
<div class="border-0 side-navbar" id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " href="#!">
            <a href="{{ url('/ViewProjectorsupervisorProject/' . $projects->id) }}"
                class="text-decoration-none">
                <button
                    class="chapter-background accordion__question {{ request()->is('ViewProjectorsupervisor') || request()->is('ViewProjectorsupervisorProject/*') ? 'open' : '' }}">{{ $project_query->title }}</button>
            </a>
        </div>
        @foreach ($projects->chapters()->orderBy('deadline')->get() as $chapter)
            <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#!">
                <a href="{{ url('/Project/'. $projects->id .'/Chapter/'.$chapter->id ) }}"
                    class="text-decoration-none">
                    <button
                        class="chapter-background accordion__question text-start {{ request()->is('Project/' . $projects->id . '/Chapter/' . $chapter->id . '*') ? 'open' : '' }}">
                        {{ $chapter->title }}
                    </button>
                </a>
                <div
                    class="accordion__collapse {{ request()->is('Project/' . $projects->id . '/Chapter/' . $chapter->id . '*') ? 'collapsing' : 'collapse' }}">
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        @foreach ($chapter->tasks()->orderBy('deadline')->get() as $task)
                            <a href="{{ url('/Project/' . $projects->id . '/Chapter/' . $chapter->id . '/Task/' . $task->id) }}"
                                class="text-decoration-none">
                                <div
                                    class="task task-start {{ request()->is('Project/' . $projects->id . '/Chapter/' . $chapter->id . '/Task/' . $task->id) ? 'active' : '' }}">
                                    <i
                                        class="{{ request()->is('Project/' . $projects->id . '/Chapter/' . $chapter->id . '/Task/' . $task->id) ? 'active' : '' }} bi-caret-down-fill task-icon"></i>
                                    {{ $task->title }}
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        @endforeach
                        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                            <div class="add-task" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="bi bi-caret-down-fill add-task-icon"></i><i
                                    class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok... where to start. First, that URL; you have both `project_id` and `Chapter_id` with different casing; fix that. Second, `$projects` is a bad variable name for `Project::with(...)->find(...);` `find()` returns a single `Project` or `null`, so it should be `$project`. Third, `$projects->first()->project_query;` when you use `Project::find()`, that code basically becomes `Project::find(...)->first()->project_query`, which is _not_ the same result as just `$projects->project_query` (might not matter with your current usage, but could be an issue).

Comment: hello, ok i fixed them, and as for `Project::find(...)->first()->project_query;` whenever i used `$projects->project_query `i would get an error, but when i use this it would work.